# WaitforSeconds() not working as it should

Tags: c#, unity

I searched for using WaitforSeconds and used as it was mentioned(using a return type of IEnumeration and using coroutines instead of update). but it did not work. Initially it showed Waitfor Seconds and IEnumerator were not "present in the current context". I had to r-install unity to get it fixed but this problem still remains. The following is my code. Am I using WaitforSeconds in correct way? Is it the 'if' code block that ruin my complete work(I mean have I used it in wrong place)?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyCreeator : MonoBehaviour {
public float xmin,xmax,zmin,zmax;
public GameObject enemy;
public float spawnWait,StartWait,waveWait;
public int turretCount;
public int enemyCount;
int i=0;
void Update() {
    StartCoroutine (TurretWaves());
}
IEnumerator TurretWaves() {

    while (true) {  
        Vector3 pos=new Vector3(Random.Range (xmin,xmax),0.5f,Random.Range(zmin,zmax));
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(StartWait);
        while(i<turretCount) {
            //Debug.Log ("The vaue of game time in spawnwaiting is: "+Time.time);
            Instantiate (enemy, pos, Quaternion.identity);
            enemyCount++;
            i++;
            //Debug.Log ("value of i in loop is: "+i);
            //Debug.Log ("The vaue of game time is: "+Time.time);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (spawnWait);
        }
        //Debug.Log("cHECKing Before WAVE WAIT(value of time )is: "+Time.time);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waveWait);
        if(i>=turretCount) {
            i=0;
        }
        //Debug.Log("cHECKing AFTER WAVE WAIT and value of time is: "+Time.time);
        //Debug.Log ("value of i outside the while loop is: "+i);
    }
}
}
```

The code needs to wait until the spawnWait before spawning each turret and wait till the wavewait before spawning the next wave. even though the Startwait works fine, I still am unable to find the problem with others...

(I had this question asked in StackOverflow but since i did not get any answer ,and i didnt know about this specific game-development website, so sorry for the repetition)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are three yield returns. I suggest cleaning up your code. Good practice is each function/method performing a specific action.

Comment: Your while loop is while(true) . If it has to execute every time, that while is completely unnecessary.

Comment: you were running a while-true loop on every frame? just call the coroutine once in Awake() or Start()

Answer (score 4):

This bit:

```
void Update() {
    StartCoroutine (TurretWaves());
}
```

Once you start a coroutine, it will continue processing automatically. If you call `StartCoroutine` twice, you will launch two independent coroutines. If you call `StartCoroutine` once per frame, you will start a new, fully independent coroutine on every frame.

By the time your game finishes running 50 frames, you will have 50 copies of `TurretWaves` running. This is probably not what you want or expect.

If you want 1 copy of `TurretWaves`, you will need to start it exactly once:

```
void Start() {
    StartCoroutine (TurretWaves());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usualy it's a good practise to use StartCoroutine into the Start(), you're "starting" a coroutine on every update!!

[Here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) can find some examples on using StartCoroutine.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
    public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
        void Start() {
            print("Starting " + Time.time);
            StartCoroutine(WaitAndPrint(2.0F));
            print("Before WaitAndPrint Finishes " + Time.time);
        }
        IEnumerator WaitAndPrint(float waitTime) {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
            print("WaitAndPrint " + Time.time);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it that when the code ''Waits for Seconds()" it continuously run the code-blocks just before the WaitforSeconds() line?While using those debud.log code in comment i found that.Am i correct? Bcoz i think it can be exploited by me if it happens to be correct.

Comment: @SanSolo- i used a whil loop every frame in order to instantiate the enemy turret then check for their number every frame. Is it worng? I know it requires quite a bit of processing power but its seems working.

Comment: Sorry for the spelling mistakes

Comment: @AbhishekSinha if true is the condition for while, it means that block is always executed. So i don't see why you need it.

Comment: Sorry actually i actually mistyped my code...the WaitforSeconds(StartWait) should be above the while(true) statement.This will allow only a single start wait while multiple spawn and wave wait...@SanSolo